# Name does not resolve in kubernetes with docker

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

When I run `nslookup` on my docker container, I get this error

```
 nslookup  10.0.96.xx
 nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

 Name:      10.0.96.xx
 Address 1: 10.0.96.xx
```

I've read that the problem comes from docker which injects this on the `resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 10.109.0.xx
nameserver 10.96.0.xx
search devlan.xxx.corp poc.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:2 edns0
```

With kubernetes, I tried to overwrite it with the following parameters on my `PodConfFile.yaml`.

```
spec:
  dnsPolicy: "None"
#  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  dnsConfig:
   nameservers:
     - 10.109.0.xx
     - 10.96.0.xx
   searches:
     - devlan.xxx.corp
     - poc.svc.cluster.local
     - svc.cluster.local
     - cluster.local
   options:
     - name: ndots
       value: "2"
     - name: edns0
```

Do you have any advice to resolve this issue?

- Docker version: 18.03.1-ce
- go1.9.3

Comment: Is that a type in your question or does it cause your problem: `nslookup  10.>>0.96<<.xx` vs `nameserver 10.>>96.0<<.xx`? Once it is `0.96` and once `96.0`

Answer (score 3):

i found a solution to this issue .  on your Pod remove this params

> nameserver  options  searches

and add thie one

```
spec:
  dnsPolicy: Default
```

it will inherit directly the DNS configuration .

you will be able to ping a external services  .

Answer (score 0):

otherwise i found another solution much cleaner

whether your pod can't resolve a URL  and you have @IP **10.0.96.XX** in your **/etc/resolv.conf**

```
nslookup  10.0.96.xx
 nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve
```

To fix it :

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```

change @IP  address with your IP

```
Environment="KUBELET_DNS_ARGS=--cluster-dns=YOUR-IP-DNS --cluster-domain=cluster.local"
```

And restart kublet

```
systemctl restart kubelet.service
```

I hope this will help you ;)

And you can remove from Pod.yaml

> DnsPolicy